# How I use cluster.stats( ) for the result of dbscan

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, dbscan

When I write

```
db<-dbscan(mydata, eps=3, MinPts = 5, scale = FALSE, 
           method = c("hybrid", "raw","dist"), 
           seeds = TRUE, showplot = FALSE, countmode = NULL)

cluster.stats(mydata, db$cluster)

Error in db$cluster : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In as.dist.default(d) : non-square matrix
```

So ,
What is the right to write `cluster.stats( )` for the result of `dbscan`

Answer (score 0):

From the **documentation** of `cluster.stats(d, ...`

> `d` a distance object (as generated by dist) or a distance matrix between cases.
>
> `clustering` an integer vector of length of the number of cases, which indicates a clustering. The clusters have to be numbered from 1 to the number of clusters.
>
> `noisecluster` logical. If `TRUE`, it is assumed that the largest cluster number in clustering denotes a 'noise class', i.e. points that do not belong to any cluster. These points are not taken into account for the computation of all functions of within and between cluster distances including the validation indexes.

You should be using `noisecluster` with DBSCAN, so make sure the largest cluster number is the noise cluster. Unfortunately, this doesn't match the cluster numbering of the `fpc.dbscan` function, so you *will* have to correct this.

Also understand that many measures do not work very well with non-convex clusters and noise - so they may not be very useful for DBSCAN.

Note that the `R` (`fpc`) version of DBSCAN is not very fast. It could be 10x faster if it weren't written in `R` but in C or Fortran; and it does not support data indexing.

Comment: How can the order of the clusters be changed so that the largest cluster number is the noise cluster?